# Avatars are distorted on teams page

Tags: bug, status-completed, old-teams

The avatars on a Teams page are currently distorted:

[image: Distorted avatars]

This happens because the images have `width` and `height` attributes set to 100%.

```
<div class="card -user" id="team-user-873145">
    <a href="/users/873145/thomas-orozco">
        <img src="https://www.gravatar.com/avatar/0ab6f2836e0722ea0cbfeb97a74f131d?s=256&d=identicon&r=PG" width="100%" height="100%" />
        <div class="-meta">
                <div class="-name">Thomas Orozco</div>
            <div class="-role">Product Manager</div>
        </div>
    </a>
</div>
```

If you remove the `width="100%" height="100%"`, then the CSS correctly sizes the images again.

Comment: Oh my, look at all those long faces... I didn't realise work at Stack Exchange was so bad!

Comment: What browser/OS are you on?

Comment: Oh, didn’t even check other browsers for this. I’m using Firefox Nightly on Windows 8, but let me check other browsers.

Comment: Can also reproduce this in more stable versions of Firefox, and in Internet Explorer 11. It works in Chrome though (but it also works there with the proposed fix).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for alerting us to the issue. This issue has been corrected.

[image: SO Team Page with correctly proportional avatars!]